# Как сделать скриншот окна без фокуса?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Мне нужно делать скриншот определенного окна, оно развернуто, только не в фокусе и скорее всего на другом рабочем столе (win 10). Возможно ли это сделать имея какой-нибудь дескриптор окна или что-то вроде? Есть ли подобные программы?

Comment: В WinAPI это делается оконным сообщением WM_PRINT. Управляемой обертки я не знаю, к сожалению.

Answer (score 1):

Если окно безо всяких директиксов, то брать скриншот традиционным `GetDC(0)` для получения картинки всего активного декстопа. Копировать область, соответствующую области активного окна.

В .NET есть обёртка над `GetDC(0)` — `Graphics.CopyFromScreen`.

Как брать скриншоты неактивного десктопа — не знаю. Скорее всего никак, потому что наверняка рисуется только активный десктоп.